# Java - Hashfunction

Tags: java, arrays, hash, hash-function

I have to make a class in java to calculate the collision of a hash function for a table with 17021 entries. [the list of words](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/linuxwords)

[this is the hash function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU7XW.png)

"a" is either 33, 37, 39 or 41.

x_0 ist the first char of the String and x_k-1 the last char.

[This is my program](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bHs5GMtkCf/)

Unfortunately, I always get a number which is bigger than 17021 as result.
But this is impossible. I don't know why it doesn't work.

I am little bit desperate, because I have tried to find the failure for a long time, but I am not able to find it.

It would be really nice, if one of you guys knows what's my mistake.
I have learned Java for 5 months now, so that you know how big my skill level might be.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This class calculates the hash value of strings.
 * 
 * @author Chris
 *
 */
public class ZeichenkettenHashfunktion {

    /**
     * Counts how often the same hash value is calculated
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public int berechneKollisionen() throws IOException {

        // Implement the data
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("F:\\eclipse\\eclipse-workspace\\Info 2 Aufgabe 19\\words.txt");
        // Create a Buffer
        BufferedReader inBuffer = new BufferedReader(reader);

        // Set Variables
        int hashwert = 0;
        int kollisionen = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int[] hashwerte = new int[17021];

        // fill in the field up to 17020
        while (i < 17021) {
            hashwerte[i] = i;

            i += 1;

        }

        // takes the first string of the list
        String line = inBuffer.readLine();

        // calculates his hash value
        hashwert = this.berechneHashwert(line, 33);

        // delete the number of the hash value
        hashwerte[hashwert] = 1000000;

        // Check, whether it works
        System.out.println(hashwerte[hashwert]);

        // go step by step over the array
        while (line != null) {
            line = inBuffer.readLine();

            // to exclude the last line
            if (line != null) {
                // calculate the hash value of the current line
                hashwert = this.berechneHashwert(line, 40);

                // if there is 1000000 on the place of the hash value, then raise the collision
                // counter by 1
                if (hashwerte[hashwert] == 1000000) {
                    kollisionen += 1;
                    System.out.println(" " + kollisionen);
                }

                // if there is the hash value on the place of the hash value, then replace it by
                // 1000000
                if (hashwerte[hashwert] == hashwert) {
                    hashwerte[hashwert] = 1000000;
                }
            }

        }

        inBuffer.close();
        reader.close();

        return kollisionen; // return collision counter

    }

    /**
     * Calculates the hash value of a string
     * 
     * @param eingabe
     * @param zahl
     * @return
     */
    public int berechneHashwert(String eingabe, int zahl) {

        // Set variables
        int laenge = eingabe.length();
        char[] zerteilung = new char[laenge];
        int hashwert = 0;
        int a = zahl;

        // breaks the string down into chars
        while (laenge != 0) {
            zerteilung[laenge - 1] = eingabe.charAt(laenge - 1);
            laenge -= 1;
        }
        // Set laenge back to the length
        laenge = eingabe.length();

        // calculates the hash value
        hashwert = this.berechneHashwertIntern(zerteilung, laenge, hashwert, a) % 17021;

        return hashwert;
    }

    /**
     * auxiliary function to calculate the hash value
     * 
     * @param zerteilung
     * @param laenge
     * @param hashwert
     * @param a
     *            a is a number, which is called as good for hash functions by
     *            scientist
     * @return
     */
    private int berechneHashwertIntern(char[] zerteilung, int laenge, int hashwert, int a) {

        // calculate the last part of the formula
        hashwert = (a * zerteilung[laenge - 1]) % 17021;
        laenge -= 2;

        // calculate the formula from the end to the beginning
        while (laenge != 0) {
            hashwert = (a * (zerteilung[laenge] + hashwert)) % 17021;

            laenge -= 1;

        }

        return hashwert;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code as text and not an image?

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not in an external link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite understand your problem. You have an input file of about 45,000 lines, which you try to map to a HashMap of 17021 entries. So per definition, even if you inserted each entry by using "previous position + 1" (i.e., without hashing, as if it were a list), you would have about 28000 collisions. Are you sure the size of your hash table makes (any) sense given the size of the input?
Because your function is fixed, I actually get 29778 collisions.

Comment: Thank you Guido <3 I didnt realize that, because my prof said, that this file just has 17021 entries. And I have believed him -.- Then my program ist correct. Thank you very much :3

Comment: Hi Markus,
why did my reply "not provide an answer to the question"? The question was essentially, "why does it not work", and I pointed out the reason why I cannot work by definition. To me, this is "an answer to the question"...?
(I admit that the leading sentence may be less than optimal, but that's not the main point I am making...)